# Dynamically Creating and Positioning UILabels of Different Sizes

Tags: ios, ios5

I am creating dynamic UILabels and then adding them to the view. The labels are in vertical layout. Like this:

Label 1

Label 2

Label 3

Each label can be of different height. So in order to accomodate the height I use the following code. The Label 2 uses Label 1 position and height to adjust itself on the view.

```
    -(void) createAboutLabel 
{
    self.aboutLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.nameLabel.frame.origin.x, self.nameLabel.frame.origin.y + self.nameLabel.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 40)];

    self.aboutLabel.text = self.selectedVegetableCategory.about;
    self.aboutLabel.font = [Utility getFont:@"Sinhala Sangam MN" size:14];
 //   [self.aboutLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.aboutLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.aboutLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [self.aboutLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.aboutLabel];
}
```

I am trying to find a better way of achieving the dynamic label layout.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I have updated the original question!

Comment: did u get the answer for this?.i am facing the same problem.can u help?

Answer (score 1):

By passing  width & font, height can be retrieved  -

NSString *theText = myLabel.text;
CGFloat width = myLabel.frame.size.width ;
CGSize theSize = [theText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSize(width,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

It  will return  the size  from that  extract height.
CGFloat myLabelHeight = theSize.height;

Hope this should help.